# What is the lifecycle of Watch App?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

There are two subclasses of `WKInterfaceController` in my Apple Watch app. 
The first one is the entrance of another one, their relationships is `nextPage` with the Interface Builder.
For the `awakeWithContext`, `willActivate` and `didDeactivate` method in each InterfaceController, I printed them all out while watch app launching.

And I got this output:

```
awakeWithcontext -> First
awakeWithContext －> Second
willActivate －> First
willActivate -> Second
didDeactivate －> Second
```

and I swipe to the next InterfaceController:

```
willActivate -> Second
didDeactivate －> First
```

So now the question is:

Will all the `awakeWithContext` method of all InterfaceControllers in Watch App be fired as long as launched?

What about the `willActivate` method?

Answer (score 7):

The life cycle of watchOS apps is as described below.

**`awakeWithContext`**

When initializing the page, `awakeWithContext` will be called. This is the first method to be called, and no UI is displayed yet.

You should do something like updating model arrays for table views, setting properties, etc in `awakeWithContext`. This method has a very similar job to initializers in simple classes (`init()`), but this time in `WKInterfaceController`s.

The answer of your first question:

> `awakeWithContext` will be called on ALL PAGES as soon as the watchOS
>   app launches.

**`willActivate`**

When the interface controller is about to be displayed, `willActivate` will be called.

You should update label values, actions and anything else related to view elements there.

The answer of your second question:

> `willActivate` will be called on ALL PAGES as soon as the watchOS app
>   launches, but in contrast with `awakeWithContext`, this will be called
>   again as soon as you view the controller (in other words, when you
>   navigate to that desired interface).

For the first time you launch the app, all controllers' `didDeactivate` will be called, except the current, and when going to another, its `willActivate` will be called prior to `didDeactivate` being called on first one.

So the life cycle is:

1- `awakeWithContext` of all views

2- `willActivate` of all views

3- `didDeactivate` of all views, except the first one (the current one)

And when swiping to the second:

1- `willActivate` of the second view

2- `didDeactivate` of the first view

Answer (score 0):

`awakeWithContext` is called on initialization. This method will be called on all your pages in your watch app on launch.

`willActivate` is called when the interface controller is about to be displayed. The reason your second interface controller's `willActivate` followed by `didDeactivate` is called, is because it's the next page that can be onscreen. This happens in order to help load the next interface controller with relevant data since it may come on screen soon.

Therefore, if you had a 3rd page interface controller its `willActivate` followed by `didDeactivate` would be called when the 2nd interface controller is onscreen.

[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/willActivate) on `willActivate`. [Page-based navigation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/InterfaceStyles.html) on the watch may not explicitly say this, but they always help to read.